# Why facebook access token from Spring Social returns empty array, while Facebook Graph Api token works fine

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, authentication, spring-social

I need to make a simple query `SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id={friendId}` in my Facebook app that I build with help of Spring Social. To do this I use authentication code provided by this library. The authentication works fine. But the query mentioned above returns an empty array. I would like to emphasizes that all the needed permissions are [given](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/) (user_likes and friend_likes). However similar access token given to me by [facebook graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) works perfectly.

[Access token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) from Facebook says that both tokens are valid and have needed permissions. The only difference in the duration of token validity: my app gives  token that expires in 2 months and Graph Api gives for an hour.

What is the reason of this strange behaviour? Why token given by my app with needed permissions is unable to make this query. How to fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
Ok, it seems that Facebook gives access token for application that is different from access token of a user. So now the question is how to get user's access token with Spring Social Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit a post request to spring social ConnectController for the specific provider  e.g. http://wwww.yourdomain:8089/connect/facebook. Spring social then will redirect the user to facebook authorization page where the user will grant your app with the asked permissions and send back a code to your server. Spring social then will exchange that code for an access token. You need to establish a connection for that user to be able to perform requests against FB on his/her behalf. Here is a doc page that might help http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html/connecting.html